# How to style a Vaadin Table row with multi-row drag mode enabled

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, vaadin, styling

**Problem**

Recently I came across a weird bug in a Vaadin application. When dragging a table row, the row would sometimes appear at a different position than the mouse cursor. I also noticed that the dragged row didn’t have the correct CSS style.

[image: The same thing in Vaadin Sampler with browser-tweaked styles]

I replicated the behavior on the [Vaadin Sampler](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/) page by going to the [Table demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/table), enabling MULTIROW drag mode and applying some custom CSS in Chrome to make it more visible.

Here’s the CSS I used:

```
.v-table .v-table-row .v-table-cell-content {
   background-color: red;
   font-size: 3em;
}
```

Strangely this would only happen when dragging the **currently selected** row and with the **MULTIROW** drag mode enabled.

I wasn’t able to find out how the dragged row's code looks. Also, googling around for any information on styling dragged items produced no results.

I did however find out, that **the dragged row exists outside the scope of the table component**, which means that CSS rules with table-specific selectors no longer apply.

**Solution**

1. Change drag mode to *ROW* (but I guess you have a reason to want MULTIROW)
2. Change your CSS to less specific rules - i.e. ".our-awesome-class" instead of ".v-table .v-table-row .v-table-cell-content .our-awesome-class". While this may work fine, it will make your rules more general and could break your styles.
3. I searched the Vaadin theme files and found the *v-drag-element* class. This class is present on the dragged row, but I didn't manage to make it work for the **selected row**.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

It looks to me like a Vaadin bug (since it seems to work nicely without MULTIROW mode).